# Why I can't use apt-get command on an Ubuntu VM running in my client datacenter? Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-18.04, apt

I am not so into Linux. On an Ubuntu VM on a client production environment it seems that I can't use apt-get command.

I will try to explain the situation in details:

first thing: at the startup of the system I have this error message:

```
 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

25 packages can be updated.
20 updates are security updates.

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

**NOTE:** The Internet connectivity works fine. I can download things using **wget** command.

Then I have to install **ntpdate** tool, so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

but I obtain this error message:

> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Here a screenshot of the complete error:

[image]

Also trying:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but I am facing the same problem.

I know that this Ubuntu system run in a virtual machine that is on the data center of the client. I also know that there is a firewall blocking some ports.

What could be the cause of this issue? How can I try to better investigate and ask a resolution?

Comment: By default you would need ports 53 (DNS) and 80 (HTTP) for apt-get (it seem you do not use FTP). Can you `ping` the domain? Can you do an `nslookup` of the domain?